# Метод find() MongoDB не выводит коллекцию

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

У меня имеется следующий JSON:

```
{"Теория кодирования":{
  "Темы для повторения":[
        "основные понятия",
        "помехоустойчивое кодирование",
        "понятие связи",
        "энтропия",
        "Теорема Шеннона",
        "Линейный код",
      "Размерность",
        "Кодовое минимальное слово",
        "Расстояние",
        "Скорость кода",
        "Соотношения между основными параметрами кода",
        "БХЧ",
        "Кольца, конечные поля",
        "Неравенство Варшамова-Гильберта"],
    "Книги":[
        "Блейхут Теория и практика кодов...",
        "Сагалович Ю.Л. Введение в алгебраические коды"]
  },
"Теория принятия решений":{
    "Книги":[
    "Э.Н. Гордеев Элементы исследования операций"]
  }
 }
}
```

В своей бд я создаю коллекцию:

```
db.createCollection("materials",*мой JSON*)
```

В ответ получаю, что все удачно создано. Однако, когда вызываю команду

```
db.materials.find()
```

коллекция ничего не выводит. Хотелось бы узнать почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Ваша коллекция пуста. Вы ничего туда не добавили. Проверьте `db.collectionName.count()`

Comment: Согласен, попробовал команду db.materials.insert(), получил результат WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }), однако команда db.materials.count() по-прежнему выдает 0

Comment: а что показывает `show collections`?

Comment: коллекция присутствует в списке

Comment: кирилица нигде не затесалась?

Comment: проблема решилась максимально просто, я оказался слишком невнимательным, благодарю

Comment: так поведайте нам, в чем была проблема. Мы тоже можем оказаться в подобной ситуации

Comment: у меня было почему то две коллекции, одна materials, а вторая (видимо давненько созданная) material :)